# What value to give JSF Radiobuttons in Form?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, xhtml

I have two radiobuttons in a form in my jsf xhtml file but I don't know which values I should give them and which value to give to my submit button. The two radiobuttons decide whether the user wants to deposit or withdraw something form his account (it's a simmulation of an online atm for a class I'm in) I have a Bean in which both methods to deposit or to withdraw are in but I can't figure this out. (I'm new, sorry)

```
<h:outputLabel class="form-check-label">
                <h:selectOneRadio value="#{}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{}" 
                         itemLabel="Deposit" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{}" 
                         itemLabel="Withdraw" />
                </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:outputLabel>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <h:selectOneRadio value="#{}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{}" 
                     itemLabel="Deposit" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{}" 
                     itemLabel="Withdraw" />
 </h:selectOneRadio>
```

`<h:selectOneRadio value="#{}">` put the variable where you want to put the selected value

`<f:selectItem itemValue="#{}" itemLabel="Deposit" />` put the value of the radio button

see examples here [h:radiobutton mkyoung](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-radio-buttons-example/) and [h:radiobutton tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_selectoneradio_tag.htm)